# ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource: No message found under code 'Size.userForm.username'

Tags: spring, freemarker

Help me please. I use Spring MVC and Freemarker 2.3.27 in my web application and I can't catch bindingResult.errors on my FTL page. When I attempt to create wrong user with empty username, I have error: No message found under code 'Required' for locale 'ru'. But when i create user with short name (<6 characters) the message displays in my registration form. Why is this happening? Here is my code:

```
@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return User.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        User user = (User) o;
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors,"username","Required");
        if(user.getUsername().length()<6||user.getUsername().length()>32){
            errors.rejectValue("username","Size.userForm.username");
        }
        if(userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername())!=null){
            errors.rejectValue("username","Duplicate.userForm.username");
        }
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors,"password","Required");
        if(user.getPassword().length()<6||user.getPassword().length()>32){
            errors.rejectValue("password","Size.userForm.password");
        }
        if(!user.getConfirmPassword().equals(user.getPassword())){
            errors.rejectValue("confirmPassword","Different.userForm.password");
        }

    }
}
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {
   ....

    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String goToRegistrationForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());
        return "registration";
    }
    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm")User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "registration";
        }
        userService.saveUser(userForm);
        securityService.autologIn(userForm.getUsername(),userForm.getPassword());
        return "redirect:/hello";
    }
}
```

My WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "aquaplant")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
     .....
    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new 

ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
            messageSource.setBasenames("validation");
            messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
            //messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
            return messageSource;
        }
   }
```

My project structure:

```
 {main
       resources
                Resource Bundle 'validation'
                           validation_en.properties
                           validation_ru.properties}
```

Comment: Do you have the `Required` message in `validation_ru.properties`?

Comment: Yes, I have this message in my validation_ru.properties.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my validation_ru.properties. I saved this file in UTF format in Notepad, but Notepad adds an invisible Unicode character BOM to the beginning of the file.....